# The science of energy manipulation powers

Tags: energy, super-powers

Trying to create a hero with energy manipulating powers but I know nothing about energy and Captain Atom and Doctor Solar seem pretty accurate with showing versatility with using this sort of power.
How do I learn about it?

Answer (score 2):

Read books on introductory physics and make up something based on that.

I just saw a documentary on the history of American comic books, and in it Stan Lee and other creators explained how they took up the popular (as in all over the media) science of their time and then made something up based on that. I mean, how does getting exposed to gamma rays make anyone have the power to burn or fly or change into a superstrong being? It doesn't. The "science" in comic books is not science but fantasy using elements of science. So if you are not writing hard SF, then you need not feel bound by logic or truth and can make up anything you want – just like all the other writers have done before you. Good superhero comics are truthful on a psychological level, not in the portraial of superpowers.